# Android Application Crashes in this part conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()

Tags: android

I am very new to Android application development. In this practice application that I'm making, when then application launches, it first checks if the locationprovider is enabled and that data is enabled.

I have already set the permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in the Androidmanifest but still the application crashes.

I'd want to ask for some advice on how I could solve this problem.

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService (LOCATION_SERVICE);
       ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       boolean statCheck = locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
       boolean dataConCheck =  conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

       if (statCheck == false) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
         startActivity(intent);
    }

       if (dataConCheck == false) {
         Intent intent = new Intent (Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
```

}

```
    05-11 00:58:52.349: W/dalvikvm(1354): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cheapapps.productivity.inviter/cheapapps.productivity.inviter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at cheapapps.productivity.inviter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    05-11 00:58:52.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: "Crashes" is not an adequate description of the problem. Post the stack trace (logcat) and details on what you have done in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi! I tried the "comment out" some parts of the code in attempt to point what causes the application to stop during launch. Somehow I have pointed it in this part "boolean dataConCheck =  conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();"

Comment: Hi! I have already included the "logcat." As I have said, I'm still very new to this and I still don't know how to fully utilize yet all the tools that are available in eclipse. Regarding the steps that I did, I also tried to "clean" the project and also tried to rewrite the permission in the manifest file. Still I have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add uses permission -> `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or  `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` , depending on your requirement.

[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html)